# Can't open Windows firewall?

Tags: windows, firewall

I accidentally opened a virus on my windows XP, now i can't open the Windows firewall.

Control Panel > Click on Windows firewall > Gives me this error - "Unable to display Windows Firewall settings due to an unidentified problem"

What shall i do?

(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Related: [How to restore Windows Firewall after some malware deleted its service?](http://superuser.com/q/385662/10259)

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the following code into Notepad and save as sharedaccess.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess]
"DependOnGroup"=hex(7):00,00
"DependOnService"=hex(7):4e,00,65,00,74,00,6d,00,61,00,6e,00,00,00,57,00,69,00,\
  6e,00,4d,00,67,00,6d,00,74,00,00,00,00,00
"Description"="Provides network address translation, addressing, name resolution and/or intrusion prevention services for a home or small office network."
"DisplayName"="Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)"
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,76,00,63,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,\
  6b,00,20,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,73,00,00,00
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
"Start"=dword:00000002
"Type"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Epoch]
"Epoch"=dword:00002cd0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters]
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  69,00,70,00,6e,00,61,00,74,00,68,00,6c,00,70,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile\AuthorizedApplications]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile\AuthorizedApplications\List]
"%windir%\\system32\\sessmgr.exe"="%windir%\\system32\\sessmgr.exe:*:enabled:@xpsp2res.dll,-22019"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\AuthorizedApplications]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile\AuthorizedApplications\List]
"%windir%\\system32\\sessmgr.exe"="%windir%\\system32\\sessmgr.exe:*:enabled:@xpsp2res.dll,-22019"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Setup]
"ServiceUpgrade"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Setup\InterfacesUnfirewalledAtUpdate]
"All"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Enum]
"0"="Root\\LEGACY_SHAREDACCESS\\0000"
"Count"=dword:00000001
"NextInstance"=dword:00000001
```

Then double-click the file to merge the contents to the registry. After you double click it a message will appear asking if you are sure, choose ‘Yes’ or ‘OK.’  The Services entry will be created. Restart Windows (you must restart or the next steps will NOT work).

After restarting Windows:
Click Start > Run > Type `cmd` click **OK**.

In the window that appears, type `NETSH FIREWALL RESET` and press Enter.

Go to the Control Panel (Start > Control Panel) and double click ‘Windows Firewall’.  If you do not see ‘Windows Firewall’ click ‘Switch to Classic View’ in the top left corner of the Control Panel.  You should now be able to configure Windows Firewall’s settings.

*Source: [Due to an unidentified problem, Windows cannot display Windows Firewall settings](http://www.johnmag4u.com/blog/2006/09/27/fix-due-to-an-unidentified-problem-windows-cannot-display-windows-firewall-settings/)*