# Unable to control Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall

I have no other firewall software installed. Had Panda but removed it when I saw this happen. In the Windows Firewall applet, I'm unable to do anything. Unable to turn on/off. The "Use recommended settings" button does nothing. Windows 7 Ultimate x64

EDIT:
The only reason I care about the Windows Firewall, even though I don't use it, is because some apps (for example, my printer driver) are programmed to poke a hold through the firewall and when the process crashes, the driver fails to install. So I can't print.

Comment: I recall XP had a command to reinstall the firewall after malware corruption. Win7 might have similar. Maybe a regsvr or rundll or some sort command of some sort with a dll..  But I looked for something for win7 there's this  you could try https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/windows_firewall_diagnostic   also http://superuser.com/questions/385662/how-to-restore-windows-firewall-after-some-malware-deleted-its-service